# json encoding - Why do utf8 and utf-8 produce different outputs?

Tags: json, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

These two commands output different results:

```
In [102]: json.dumps({'Café': 1}, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8')
Out[102]: '{"Caf\xc3\xa9": 1}'

In [103]: json.dumps({'Café': 1}, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf8')
Out[103]: u'{"Caf\xe9": 1}'
```

What's the difference between `utf-8` and `utf8`?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the second iteration returns a Unicode object.

It seems strange but the documentation calls this out:

> If ensure_ascii is False, the result may contain non-ASCII characters and the return value may be a unicode instance.

It would appear that only "UTF-8" works with `ensure_ascii=False` AND if the input is a UTF-8 encoded string (Not Unicode). With a Unicode input:

```
>>> json.dumps({u'Caf€': 1}, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8')
u'{"Caf\u20ac": 1}'
```

With `ensure_ascii=False`, all other valid encodings return a Unicode instance.

If you set `ensure_ascii=True`, then the encoding is consistent and works with other encoding, such as "windows-1252" (The input needs to be a Unicode)

I guess the rationale is that JSON should be ASCII and all encodings should be escaped, even when it's UTF-8.

To avoid any surprises follow these rules:

**For proper spec. ASCII JSON:**

1. Pass Unicode object
2. Call:

   ```
   >>> json.dumps({u'Caf€': 1}, ensure_ascii=True)
   '{"Caf\\u20ac": 1}'
   ```

**UTF-8 Encoded JSON:**

1. Pass Unicode object
2. Call:

   ```
   >>> json.dumps({u'Caf€': 1}, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")
   '{"Caf\xe2\x82\xac": 1}'
   ```